# Segmentation fault: 11 With Array Assignment in Loop Using x86 GNU GAS Assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu, gnu-assembler

This question is similar to another question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255771/error-raised-when-attempting-to-assign-value-at-index-of-array-with-x86-assembly). I am attempting to write the Assembly version of the following in `c/c++`:

```
int x[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 x[i] = i;
}
```

Essentially, creating an array storing the values `1` through `9`.

My current logic is to create a label that loops up to `10` (calling itself until reaching the end value). In the label, I have placed the instructions to update the array at the current index of iteration. However, after compiling with `gcc filename.s` and running with `./a.out`, the error `Segmentation fault: 11` is printed to the console. My code is below:

```
.data
  x:.fill 10, 4
  index:.int 0
  end:.int 10

.text
.globl _main
_main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $16, %rsp
  jmp outer_loop
  leave
  ret

outer_loop:
 movl index(%rip), %eax;
 cmpl end(%rip), %eax
 jge end_loop
 lea x(%rip), %rdi;
 mov index(%rip), %rsi;
 movl index(%rip), %eax;
 movl %eax, (%rdi, %rsi, 4)
 incl index(%rip)
 jmp outer_loop
 leave
 ret

end_loop:
  leave
  ret
```

Oddly the code below

```
lea x(%rip), %rdi;
mov index(%rip), %rsi;
movl index(%rip), %eax;
movl %eax, (%rdi, %rsi, 4)
```

works only if it is not in a label that is called repetitively. Does anyone know how I can implement the code above in a loop, without `Segmentation fault: 11` being raised? I am using `x86` Assembly on MacOS with `GNU GAS` syntax compiled with `gcc`.

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197647/assembly-x86-loop-segmentation-fault) question as different Assembly syntax is being used and the scope of the problem is different.

Comment: I have a dumb question... why not just compile / view the assembly directly rather than writing it yourself?

Comment: @IlanKeshet That is a possibility, however, I am merely writing the code myself for educational purposes.

Comment: @IlanKeshet : Some people like to do useless stuff for fun - myself included.

Comment: **local variables naturally map to registers, not static storage**.  You're making life difficult for yourself by bloating your code to keep locals in named static storage locations instead of registers.  If you do need to store/reload them (e.g. so you can pass the address of a local to another function), do it on the stack like a compiler.  Your asm is like what a compiler would do for `static volatile int i = 0;`. (`volatile` because a compiler will still optimize by keeping it in a register unless you anti-optimize for consistent debugging with GDB, because debug-info doesn't work on regs)

Comment: @PeterCordes I did not know about using the stack to store variables. If possible, do you have an example in `x86` `gnu`? Thank you.

Comment: @Ajax1234: look at compiler output for a function that does `volatile int foo = 1;`: gcc will either use the red-zone below RSP, or `sub $rsp, 8` / `mov $1, (%rsp)` / `add $8, %rsp` / `ret`.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116), esp. the link to Matt Godbolt's CppCon 2017 talk.  But remember, you don't need to use memory at all when you have lots of registers.  Just use comments to keep track of which values are in which registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much. That is quite helpful.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain how the post can be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a 64-bit instruction to access a 32-bit area of memory :

```
mov index(%rip), %rsi;
```

This results in `%rsi` being assigned the contents of memory starting from `index` and ending at `end` (I'm assuming no alignment, though I don't remember GAS's rules regarding it). Thus, `%rsi` effectively is assigned the value `0xa00000000` (assuming first iteration of the loop), and executing the following `movl %eax, (%rdi, %rsi, 4)` results in the CPU trying to access the address that's not mapped by your process.

The solution is to remove the assignment, and replace the line after it with `movl index(%rip), %esi`. 32-bit operations are guaranteed to always clear out the upper bits of 64-bit registers, so you can then safely use `%rsi` in the address calculation, as it's going to contain the current index and nothing more.

Your debugger would've told you this, so please do use it next time.